# Save database on external hard drive

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating some databases using PostgreSQL but I want to save them on an external hard drive due to lack of memory in my computer.

How can I do this?

Comment: I need 4 times the storage capacity that my laptop can offer. Since I installed PostgreSQL in my computer, should I install it again in the external hard drive?

Comment: There is no need for the database files to be on the same disk that PostgreSQL is installed on.

Answer (score 9):

You can store the database on another disk by specifying it as the `data_directory` setting. You need to specify this at startup and it will apply to all databases.

You can put it in `postgresql.conf`:

```
data_directory = '/volume/path/'
```

Or, specify it on the command line when you start PostgreSQL:

```
postgres -c data_directory='/volume/path/'
```

Reference: [18.2. File Locations](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html)

Comment: I'm trying "data_directory /Volumes/NameOfMyHardDrive" but I receive the following: data_directory: command not found

Comment: You need to put it in `postgresql.conf` or on the command line. I've added these to my answer.

Comment: I have changed the data_directory but after that, postgres cluster status is down and psql can't connect to server!

Answer (score 3):

**STEP 1:** If postgresql is running, stop it:

```sh
sudo systemctl stop postgresql
```

**STEP 2:** Get the path to access your hard drive.
(if Linux) Find and mount your hard drive by:

```sh
# Retrieve your device's name with:
sudo fdisk -l
# Then mount your device
sudo mount /dev/DEVICE_NAME YOUR_HD_DIR_PATH
```

**STEP 3:** Copy the existing database directory to the new location (in your hard drive) with `rsync`.

```sh
sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql YOUR_HD_DIR_PATH
```

Then rename the previous postgres main dir with `.bak` extension to prevent conflicts

```sh
sudo mv /var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/lib/postgresql/11/main.bak
```

*Note: my postgres version was 11. Replace in path with your version.*

**STEP 4:** Edit postgres configuration file:

```sh
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf
```

Change the `data_directory` line with:

```sh
data_directory = 'YOUR_HD_DIR_PATH/postgresql/11/main'
```

**STEP 5:** Restart Postgres & Check everything is working

```sh
sudo systemctl start postgresql
pg_lsclusters
```

Output should shows status as 'online'

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory                      Log file
11  main    5432 online postgres YOUR_HD_DIR_PATH/postgresql/11/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
```

**Finally** your can access your PostgresSQL with:

```sh
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Comment: I have changed the data_directory but after that, postgres cluster status is down and psql can't connect to server!
If I undo my changes of data_dir, everything works fine.Where am I missing sth?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following the walkthrough [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-18-04). This worked well for me and is similar to @Antiez's answer.

Currently, I am trying to do the same and the only conflict that I'm having at the moment is that it seems there is an issue with PostgreSQL's incremental backup and point-in-time recovery proccesses. I think it has something to do with folder permissions. If I try uploading a ~30MB csv to the postgres db, it will crash and the server will not start again because files cannot be written to the pg_wal directory. The only file in that directory is 000000010000000000000001 and does not move on to 000000010000000000000002 etc. while writing to a new table.

My stackoverflow post looking for a solution to this issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938577/why-is-my-postgres-database-working-for-a-while-and-then-not-able-to-start-serv).