# Storing Postgres Database on External Hard Drive through Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am new to Postgresql, and look for some help. My question is that I want to save the data/tables into another remote hard drive to which my machines connect but the solutions from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62025/postgresql-database-on-external-hd), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41938/seeting-up-a-postgresql-database-on-another-hard-drive-than-my-system-one-on-os), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070627/save-database-on-external-hard-drive) only discuss how to do this process through **Postgresql** directly, and I am wondering whether this can be done through **sqlalchemy**. Can anyone help? Thanks so much.

Below are the codes I use to create the database:

```
database = "foo"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgres://postgres@/postgres")
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute("commit")
conn.execute("drop database " + database)
conn.close()
```

Comment: The answer is: no. No no no.

Comment: You can't, and not only that, do not put a tablespace on external removable storage. It is *useless* without the information in the main data directory; you cannot just attach it to another database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't and shouldn't want to. 
Connecting to a Postgres database means that you leave the database to decide where data is stored. In the database you can define where to store data.