# Saving PostgreSQL database to an external HDD

Tags: postgresql

I need to save a database to an external HDD. This question has been asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070627/save-database-on-external-hard-drive). However, upon changing the `data_directory` variable in the `postgresql.conf` file that exists in `/usr/local/var/postgres/` to

```
data_directory = /path/to/externalHDD/directory/
```

I then restart the PostgreSQL server with `brew services restart postgresql`, but when I try to reconnect to the database via

```
psql -U username -d postgres
```

I receive the following error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Too little information. Please tell us *all* the steps you took. How did you move the data directory, etc.

Comment: Did you start the database server? And does it run? Please check the log files.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I changed the variable specifying the data directory `data_directory` to `data_directory = /path/to/externalHDD/directory/` in the `postgresql.conf` file that exists in `/usr/local/var/postgres/`. I'm on MacOS and I used Homebrew to install, so I then restarted the PostgreSQL server with the command `brew services restart postgresql`. I then ran `psql -U username -d postgres` and the error followed. Is there anything else I should expand on specifically?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Yes, I restarted it using the `brew` command stated above. How do I find the log files?

Comment: I meant to add the additional information to the query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you did was point `data_directory` somewhere else, that cannot work, because there is no data directory at the destination. You have to create the data directory using `initdb`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm almost brand new to PostgreSQL. How would one create the data directory using `initdb`? From [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/app-initdb.html) documentation it seems that the `directory` argument specified in `initdb [option...] [--pgdata | -D] directory` should be the desired directory on the external HDD, and then point `data_directory` to this same directory?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Then `postgresql.conf` will be in the original location, and the data directory on your external disk. But you might as well use the new data directory as argument to `pg_ctl start -D` (if that's how you start it) and use the `postgresql.conf` there. If that's all confusing, I understand. You should perhaps read some PostgreSQL documentation and familiarize yourself with `initdb` and `pg_ctl`.